# Strings that appear same are reflected as unequal in lua

Tags: string, replace, lua, string-comparison, substitution

I have the following function in Lua.

```
function tempchange(m1)
if type(m1) ~="string" then  return  m1 end
    for w in string.gmatch(m1, "%d%+%d*i") do
        words[#words+1]=w
      end
    for i = 1, #words do
        words[i]=string.gsub(words[i],"+","uuu")
    end
m1=string.gsub(m1,"+","uuu")
for i = 1, #words do
m1=string.gsub(m1,words[i],'"'..words[i]..'"')
end
m1=string.gsub(m1,"uuu","+")
return m1
end
```

Strings m and n are  defined as

```
m = '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,"9+i"}}'
n = '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9+i}}'
```

I expect that strings `m` and `tempchange(n)` will be same. In fact, I make the following check.

```
print(m)
print(tempchange(n))
print(type(m))
print(type(tempchange(n)))
print(m==tempchange(n))
```

The output is

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,"9+i"}}
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,"9+i"}}
string
string
false
```

So even though both strings `m` and `tempchange(n)` are strings and they look same, on comparing them we get false. It means that they are different. Why is it so? I am new to lua and trying to learn it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the post. I made it very clear and simple. It also explains the necessity of such function for me. Kindly check.

Comment: This is requirement for me. See difference between `n` and `tempstring(n)`. I can't remove the line.

Comment: I think I posted valid question with complete code and clarity. I can't code it further simple. See the difference between n and tempchange(n). The string n may contain more numbers of the form a+ib. Hence for loop is necessary. Still downvotes. Could someone explain why downvotes to new user?

Comment: Two issues: 1. You don't show the code that defines `words`. Without it, the code doesn't run, and we can't just assume where you put that line. 2. You should indent your code better. It's hard to explain, but basically, you need to indent the body of each code block one level deeper than the head and `end` of that block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not reinitializing the `words` table each time you call `tempchange`. To solve your problem, add this line to the beginning of your `tempchange` function:

```
local words = {}
```

The way you have it, every time you called `tempchange` (3 times, in your sequence of print statements above), you continued to add to `words`. This means that in this for loop:

```
for i = 1, #words do
    m1 = string.gsub(m1,words[i],'"'..words[i]..'"')
end
```

...you keep adding more quotes.

You just need to start with a new `words` table each time the function is called.

Also, I misunderstood something earlier today about your question. I apologize about that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am still curious why the final output is same for strings even without local words = {}. So when output is same, it should reflect true. Isn't it?

Comment: If `words` was global, the return value of `tempchange` would change every time you call it. That's why it would've been good to include the `words` definition in your question.

Comment: But why outputs are same irrespective of the fact that words is local or global?

Comment: It’s the mere fact that it is declared anew at the beginning of that function that matters. `local` is simply good practice, in order not to clutter global symbol space, and all the other reason to avoid global variables.

Comment: @Maths89 Just try running `for i=1,5 do print(tempchange(n)) end` with and without `local words = {}` and see the difference. That should make it quite obvious what's happening ;)